# Can't center jssor slider in a bootstrap container

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, jssor

Useing bootstrap with jssor I haven't been able to figure out how to center my slider images. I tried to zero the margins in the code below, but the images in the slider are on the left hand side of the container. How can I can the images centered inside of a bootstrap container?

```
<!-- topconent -->
<div class="container topcontent">

    <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12 text-center">
                    <h1>This is my header</h1>

    <div id="slider1_container" 
    style="position: relative; margin: 0px auto;">
        <!-- Slides Container -->
        <div u="slides" style="cursor: move; position: absolute; overflow: hidden;
        margin 0px auto; width: 630px; height: 420px;">
            <div><img u="image" src="img/mainslider/img1.jpg" /></div>
            <div><img u="image" src="img/mainslider/img2.jpg" /></div>
        </div>
    </div>

                    <p class="lead">More info</p>
            </div>
    </div>
    <!-- /.row -->

</div>
<!-- /.topcontent -->
```

Comment: What is `<div u="slides"`? Also, remove `position: absolute`

Comment: Perhaps I shouldn't have thrown so many tags at this. This "syntax" is specific to jssor I think it would break if I changed the position style (maybe someone can correct me). You can look at their docs: http://www.jssor.com/development/index.html. They answer questions on SO which is why I posted it here.

Comment: In that case you can go with `position:absolute;left:50%;margin-left:-315px;/*half width of the div*/` Do you require the wrapping divs for the images? If not, give `text-align: center` to the `slides` div

Comment: Yeah, but then when the viewport changes it isn't centered. I know there is a way to do this with jsson, I just can't figure it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok figured this out. This issue was really my inexperience\infrequent use of css more than anything else.

To center the slider I just used bootstrap containers:

```
<!-- topconent -->
<div class="container topcontent">

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12 text-center">
            <h1>This is my header</h1>

            <!-- centered container -->
            <div class="col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2 text-center">

                <div id="slider1_container" style="position: relative; 
                top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 600px; height: 300px;">
                    <!-- Slides Container -->
                    <div u="slides" style="cursor: move; position: absolute;
                    overflow: hidden; left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 600px; height: 300px;">
                        <div><img u="image" src="img/mainslider/img1.jpg" /></div>
                        <div><img u="image" src="img/mainslider/img2.jpg" /></div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <p class="lead">More info</p>

            </div>
            <!-- /.centered container -->

        </div>
        <!-- /.container -->

    </div>
    <!-- /.row -->

</div>
<!-- /.topcontent -->
```

Now my confusion was that I didn't think it was centered because the image did not stretch across the entire container so it was pulled to the left. I used the [script on the jssor site](http://www.jssor.com/development/tip-make-responsive-slider.html) to make the image scale and now it looks good. I saw the script before, but didn't use it because I wanted to "center" the image not "make it responsive" and didn't realize that this is the purpose of making it responsive! derp. It maintains the aspect ratio as well.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<div class="container topcontent">

    <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12 text-center">
                    <h1>This is my header</h1>

    <div id="slider1_container" 
    style="position: relative; margin: 0px auto;">
        <!-- Slides Container -->
        <div u="slides" style="cursor: move; position: absolute; overflow: hidden;
        margin 0px auto; width: 630px; height: 420px;">
            <div style="text-align:center;background-color:#1c2331;padding:10px">
                 <img u="image" src="img/mainslider/img1.jpg" />
            </div>
            <div style="text-align:center;background-color:#1c2331;padding:10px">
                 <img u="image" src="img/mainslider/img2.jpg" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
                    <p class="lead">More info</p>
            </div>
    </div>
    <!-- /.row -->

</div>
```